# Is there a version of GreaseMonkey that prints ALL errors to the console, like if the UserScript was a real JavaScript?

Tags: greasemonkey

Is there a version of GreaseMonkey that prints ALL errors to the console, like if the UserScript was a real JavaScript?  For example syntax errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the preference (about:config) `javascript.options.showInConsole` may control this.  See Mozilla's tips on [Setting up an extension development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Setting_up_extension_development_environment).  It's not the same thing, but since Greasemonkey is an extension running in chrome, I think it's relevant.